# Система уведомлений на php

Tags: php

Как лучше организовать систему уведомлений на php.

Comment: Уведомлений о чем? Что вы в итоге получить хотите? Рассылку e-mail, смс, сообщение на страница сайта, или может чтобы окошко в браузере всплывало, пока пользователь на вашем сайте находится?

Answer (score 4):

*День добрый.*

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите сделать систему уведомлений пользователя о новых сообщениях, если я вас правильно понял, то данную задачу можно реализовать ниже приведенным примером.

**Решение:**

Проверить получил ли пользователь сообщения мы будем через **php**, а запрос на проверку, мы будем делать через **jQuery**, функцией *setInterval()*. И еще один нюанс, все *НЕ* прочитанные сообщения у нас буду равны столбику в бд **activ=1**, тобишь, не прочитанные.

**Кодинг**

Создадим проверку на **php:**

*Назовем этот файлик new_mess.php*

```
<?php
session_start();
$zap = $_POST['zap']; //Переменная для запроса :)
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE login='".$_SESSION['login']."' AND    active='1'");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
  echo "new_mess";
}
?>
```

А теперь отправляем запросы на проверку каждые *10 секунд* на **jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $.post('new_mess.php',{zap:'zap'},function(data){
      if(data == 'new_mess'){
        alert('У Вас новое сообщение, читайте его ^_^');
      }
    });
  },10000);
});
```

*Ну, вот так, как то:) Надеюсь, помог.*

Comment: Лучше уж setTimeot вызывать, чем setInterval. Получил ответ от запроса, снова вызвал.

Answer (score 2):

Предполагая, что ТС о системе внутренних почтовых сообщений в каком-либо сервисе посоветую 
сделать так:  сделать 2 таблицы, 1 - для очереди событий, другая для сообщений когда пользователь выполняет какое-либо действие, о котором нужно оповещение, формируем событие, закладывая туда необходимые для рассылки переменные, событие заносим в базу. Сделать внешний скрипт, который будет обрабатывать эти события и рассылать уведомления (ложить обработанные события в виде уведомлений в другую таблицу) кому нужно и сколько нужно. Скрипт вбить в крон. Более менее крупные проекты, знакомые мне, делают так.